# Finding an index where the sum of all elements to the left and right are equal in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
[1, 2, 7, 10, 2, 8]
```

Consider `ArrayList` having above elements. How can we find, using Java Collections API, and element, where the sum of all elements to the left of it is equal to sum of all elements to the right of it?

For example, in above `ArrayList` for element at index 3 (i.e. 10) the two sums are the same:

```
*Sum_Left_Elements*  = 1 + 2 + 7 = 10
*Sum_right_Elements* = 8 + 2 = 10
```

Comment: if you use java8 sum using lambdas them compare sums: int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

Comment: @DanIonescu you can post that as an answer

Comment: I have two questions, comments are in my answer, but both edge cases are handled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My code handles these, but I have two questions

- How to handle empty lists, is sum considered 0 there or is it not
  acceptable?

  - (0, 1, -1) is such a case where index 0 is `empty + 0`
- Do you want first index, or all possible indexes?

  - (1, -1, 1, -1, 1) is such a case where sum is same wherever you pick

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 7, 10, 2, 8);
    // List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
    // List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(0, 1, -1);

    printEqualAtIndexes(ints);

}

private static void printEqualAtIndexes(List<Integer> ints) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
        boolean lrsumsEqual = lrsumsEqual(ints, i);
        if (lrsumsEqual) {
            System.out.println("Equal at index " + i + ", that is element " + ints.get(i));
        }
    }
}

private static boolean lrsumsEqual(List<Integer> ints, int index) {

    int left = ints.stream().limit(index).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    int right = ints.stream().skip(index + 1).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

    return left == right;
}
```

if you can't use java 8 then change lrsumsEqual to this:

```
private static boolean lrsumsEqual(List<Integer> ints, int index) {
    int left = 0;
    List<Integer> llist = ints.subList(0, index);

    for (int i : llist) {
        left = left + i;
    }

    int right = 0;
    List<Integer> rlist = ints.subList(index + 1, ints.size());

    for (int i : rlist) {
        right = right + i;
    }

    // int left = ints.stream().limit(index).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    // int right = ints.stream().skip(index + 1).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

    return left == right;
```

Comment: thank you for answer, all possible indexes.
What if Java 1.8 is not available i.e. without lambda expression can we do this ?

Comment: or instead of skip and limit use .subList(index, index)
, and instead of .sum, just do a "manual" sum of it with a for loop or something.

Comment: @EatSleepCodeRepeat, added other version

Answer (score 1):

After some feedback from Patrick Parker (see comments) and EatSleepCodeRepeat on Viktor Mellgren's questions I consider the following code a suitable pre Java 8 solution to get all indexes where the sum of all elements to the left is equal to the sum of all elements to the right.

Finding all indexes is done with *O(n)* time and not with *O(n²)* as Viktor's code but this comes at the cost of some initialization overhead. Edge cases as described by him are handled properly.

```
public static List<Integer> indexesWithLeftRightSumsEqual(List<Integer> values) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> cumulated = new ArrayList<Integer>(values.size() + 1);
    cumulated.add(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        cumulated.add(cumulated.get(i) + values.get(i));
    }
    int totalSum = cumulated.get(values.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if ((cumulated.get(i) * 2) == (totalSum - values.get(i))) {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Below is my previous solution which should be considered rather a hack after clarification by Patrick...

---

This code first calculates the total sum and then calculates the left sum for each element until (total sum - left sum - element itself), which is actually right sum, equals left sum.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 7, 10, 2, 8);
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
IntStream.range(0, list.size()).reduce(0, (leftSum, i) -> {
    Integer element = list.get(i);
    if (leftSum == sum - leftSum - element) {
        System.out.println("Element " + element + " at index " + i);
    }
    return leftSum + element;
});
```

Please note that indexes are zero based in `List` so index = 3 is correct here.

Comment: the accumulator for Stream::reduce should be "an associative, non-interfering, stateless function". This means that a) leftSum might be 0 or another intermediate value when we reduce the desired element, and b) side-effects (such as finding a desired index via side-effect) are discouraged

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I haven't been aware of that. The only thing I have checked is that List.stream() returns a sequential stream as my code obviously wouldn't work with a parallel one. I'm downvoting my answer now because it's inaccurate. Edit: Can't downvote my own answer, can you do?

Comment: nice solution! this should be the accepted answer. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have java8 and List:

```
int leftSum = leftList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
int rightSum = rightList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
if (leftSum == rightSum) {..}
```

Comment: This only checks left/right for a given element/sublist.  The question is about how to find an element where both sides sums are equal.